# How do I set my ipad to landscape mode before the app loads?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I have a landscape only app and when I test it on the iPad simulator the device starts off in portrait mode and turns to landscape mode once the app loads and messes up the entire layout of my app. How would I make the ipad go into landscape mode before the app loads because its messing up my layout? This is the code Im using in my GameViewController:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    let orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask =
        [UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape, UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape]
        return orientation
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work I went into my `info.plist` file and deleted portrait for `Supported interface orientations(iPad)`.

Comment: That is the correct answer. you should accept your own answer as soon as SO lets you.

Answer (score 1):

keep this setting in Project Target -> General

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is it. it is the simplest method

Comment: No because this will only work for the iPhone not the iPad. I have an universal app.

Comment: set orientation for both, one by one